# Hibernate duplicate columns

Tags: java, hibernate

For beginning I want to say that I am really new to Hibernate, JPA and stuff and I got a problem. When I`m starting my app it automatically duplicates some of the columns. As example, makes a copy of a column "endPoint" but names it "end_point". How can I prevent or fix this problem?
Tell me what files or classes should I show here, cause I don't know(
[Project DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT4mj.png),
[DB Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kogdS.png)

Comment: duplicates are probably foreign-keys automatically created by hibernate. your not supposed to define them explicit. Check the docs for the @Column annotation to influence the default behaviour for camel case and _.

Comment: No, `cause there are no such keys in my DB. Its just copies of existing columns, but wrote with "_"